# When does a person transcend to status "Tzadik sets his bar"?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rabbis, tzaddikim, dechiya-superseding, rogatchover

Background: we had a motivational lecture in our Kollel today, with a Rabbi praising virtues of studying Torah (towards Shavuos). He brought a couple of stories about prominent Rabbis dedicating their lives to the Torah study.

One story was about [Rogatchover Rabbi](https://seforimblog.com/2017/11/the-rogochover-and-more/)<sup>Tnahks JoelK</sup> that learned Gemmorah while being Avel (in mourning), justifying it by Pikuach Nefesh for him.

That reminded me of some Mishnayos that talk of Rabbis that justified *personal* deviation from the accepted Halachah for themselves (e.g. [Brochos 2,7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berakhot.2.7?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi) about Tavi the slave) *(not to confuse with public decrees of עת לעשות לה').*

When does a person reach that level of being allowed to deviate from the set Halachah, probably following the principle of "וְצַדִּיק בֶּאֱמוּנָתוֹ יִחְיֶה" (Havakuk 2,4)?

Comment: And it's not even just in the oral Torah. The same thing occasionally happens in Tanakh as well (e.g. Esther)

Comment: Your whole question is a scam. There are no examples. No one deviated from the Halakha. The rule about Tavi the slave was the rule beforehand too even if some onlookers didn't know it.

Comment: @DoubleAA If not צדיק maybe under הפרו תורתך? I think we have tons of those examples when one decides for himself (Eliyahoo, Rebbe?) it's time to override the Halachah.

Comment: @AlBerko Still not הפרו תורתך if it was always the Halacha. If by Eliyahu you’re referring to Har HaKarmel, that was a הוראת שעה - Eliyahu didn’t pasken that. I have no idea what you’re referring to with Rebbe.

Comment: @AlBerko What you seem to really be asking is under what grounds may one apply עת לעשות לה׳ הפרו תורתך. So why don’t you just ask that, rather than asking what seems to be a rant in disguise?

Comment: @DonielF I don't think the story of a Rabbi studying while Avel can fit into it. עת לעשות has to have serious public implications (by Rebbe I meant his personal deviations, like in the Mishna I quoted, not writing Mishna, sorry). Here, צדיק באמונתו יחה is all about personal conduct, we can't justify it with הוראת שעה.

Comment: @AlBerko I don’t understand. The story I’m assuming is false unless you can find a source for it (which I’ve tried and didn’t find). Re Rebbe - what, specifically, are you thinking of? Where do you get צדיק באמנתו from - what relevance does that have here? And הוראת שעה isn’t a person paskening for himself, so that’s irrelevant anyway.

Comment: The story of learning Torah while mourning is told regarding the Rogatchover (@DonielF) https://seforimblog.com/2017/11/the-rogochover-and-more/

Comment: @JoelK Thanks a ton, I'll put in in the question to make it real.

Comment: @DoubleAA I edited it and added Joel's source. How's it now?

Comment: @AlBerko Note the discussion in Shapiro’s article. It’s not at all clear that the Rogatchover was acting non-halachically. His behavior can be justified based on a Yerushalmi.

Comment: @JoelK That only proves my idea of judging for himself. The accepted Halacha clearly forbids it. I didn't say they were sinning, I said they lived up to their own truth (finding support elsewhere).

Comment: I didn't see the link but what is the big deal with violating halakha for pikuach nefesh? That's well established

Comment: The story with rogochover documented in an introduction from Harav Moshe Kasher who printed many of his works in the sixties, who writes the gaon based himself of yerushalmi moed katan 3, להט אחרי דברי תורה

Comment: This is also the same guy who reviewed shas on two directions of a train ride.

Comment: The correct answer to this question is probably something to do with when a *tzadik* (for lack of a better term) represents a new *hisgalus Elokis*. E.g. the Baal Shem Tov et al.